# How do you group data objects subject to several constraints?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, grouping, computer-science, graph-algorithm

I'm writing an application for a society in my campus and the main job of this application is to put members into groups subject to several

I need to determine the number of groups which depends on the number of members.
Then I need to arbitrarily/randomly select leaders for each group.
Then I need to add members to each group ensuring that each group satisfies the following constraints:

> The number of members(including the leader) should be less than or equal to 7 and greater than or equal to 4 .
>   No more than 2/3 of the group should be the same gender.
>   No more than 2/3 of the group should be the same year of study.
>   Each member is classified as coming from a certain region depending on their place of residency. All members of the group should come from the same region.

Now I'd like to know how to go about this in terms of what known data structures and abstract data types can I use? What known algorithms can come in handy? Is there already a known computer science problem similar to mine that I can read up on?... etc... I think you get the question. I've done some googling around the web but nothing really helpful so far.

Comment: I would try constraint programming (use an off-the-shelf solver) or local search.

Comment: At the university i study they use a evulutionary algorithm to solve a similar problem. This is probably the esiest way to respect all your conditions.

Comment: @AbcAeffchen what's the name of that algorithm and have they published anything about it online?

Comment: @David Eisentat thanks alot I'll definitely look up on that.

Comment: It has no name. An evulutionary algorithm is only a concept of an algorithm. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evolutionary_algorithm

Its a search algorithm, that guess solutions and rates them by a fitnessfunction. then it trys to find better solutions by combining the solutions of the last round. so you most likly geht better solutions.